# Heroku Ruby-on-Rails app won't load, logs look fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am following [Ruby On Rails Book Tutorial, Chapter 2, toy_app](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app)

I created repository in BitBucket, https://bitbucket.org/Marium36/toy_app/src/master/

And I am learning to deploy early and often to Heroku, https://salty-wave-17330.herokuapp.com/

On my local Ubuntu VM, I can perfectly load `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3000/users`

On Heroku I can go to https://salty-wave-17330.herokuapp.com/

However, when I go to https://salty-wave-17330.herokuapp.com/users, I get the error:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>   If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

The build logs look perfectly fine, https://bitbucket.org/Marium36/toy_app/src/master/build

What can be the problem?

Comment: You should look at the server log (there should be a dropdown in upper right corner with 'Open Log' item), not at the build log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you can do:

**First:** Check your **server logs (not build logs)**, this will most likely tell you where the problem is - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs

**Secondly:** Add an error monitor like [Airbrake](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/airbrake) - Check out **Errors and Exceptions** section on this page - https://elements.heroku.com/addons

Also, build logs are only related to deploying the app, you have to check the server logs to know why your server is throwing an error.

Comment: Thank you I will check server logs. When I attempt to add airbrake via command line, I get prompted for Credit Card info...

Comment: there is a free version, heroku won't charge you unless you upgrade